# are there implicit cookies created while web navigation? / httpOnly flag

Tags: php, security, session, cookies, httponly

In my website I am not using any kind of cookies, everything goes through server-side session handling. (no `setcookie` instruction at all)

But still, using Acunetix website vulnerability checker, I get a report about "Session cookie without httpOnly flag set"

Is there something I'm missing? Are there any implicit cookies anyway?

Thank you

Comment: session_start() does an implicit setcookie() to store the session ID in the client browser as a cookie... **UNLESS** you've enabled trans_sid sessions in PHP, which is a horribly stupidly bad idea

Comment: I see, that answers my question. How do I set the httpOnly flag for these cookies?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Comment: thank you, I also took note of the `session.cookie-secure` parameter on my way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions are using cookies! Unless you transport the session id in URLs (which isn't good either), a session sets a cookie. A session consists of the server-side data storage and a *session cookie*, which contains a random id *associating the client with the server-side data*.

Comment: thank you, is there any sensitive datas in the client side? How to apply the httponly flag to them?

Comment: there'll only be sensitive data on the client if you put it there. a session ID **CAN** be sensitive, e.g. the session ID for your bank's login, v.s. a generally useless session for your average angst-ridden teenybopper's facebook login.

Comment: No, I'm absolutely not storing any personal nor sensitive informations. I'll protect it anyway. Thank you guys, being a beginner has this cool that you learn every day :-)